# How to Return the HTTP Call Response in C#

Tags: c#, .net, http

I am trying to return the response of `productRating` in this HTTP call. I have tried several ways but haven't been successful. Any idea? The response is a json with an object that I want to get access to the streamInfo>avgRatings>_overall

```
public double GetRatings(string productId)
    {
        const string URL = "https://comments.au1.gigya.com/comments.getStreamInfo";
        var apiKey = "3_rktwTlLYzPlqkzS62-OxNjRDx8jYs-kV40k822YlHfEx5VCu93fpUo8JtaKDm_i-";
        var categoryId = "product-ratings";
        var urlParams = "?apiKey=" + apiKey + "&categoryID=" + categoryId + "&streamID=" + productId + "";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(client.GetAsync(urlParams).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        var productrating = (response["streamInfo"]["avgRatings"]["_overall"]);
        return;

    }
```

[image]

GetRatings Erroe: not all code paths return a value.

Productrating Error:can not apply indexing with [] to an expression of type HttpResponseMessage

return Error: an object of a type convertable to double is required

Comment: ApiCall() do not return anything

Comment: @ Rawitas Krungkaew  Could you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: @Negin, there is no return statement in ApiCall()

Comment: You define your GetRatings method as returning a `double` value. But in your `return;` statement, you are not returning any value.

Answer (score 1):

ApiCall has to return something. Looking at the example below.

```
@functions {

    public static string ApiCall()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
@{
    var ratings = ApiCall();
}

@if (ratings != null)
{
    <div class="gig-rating-stars" content=@ratings></div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I am using this function for POST API Call and it returns response string and if you want to add security features you can send it in JObject because its the secure channel to send Jobject as a parameter on URL**

**## Code Start ##**

```
protected string RemoteApiCallPOST(JObject elements, string url)
        {
            try
            {
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                // JObject jsonResult = new JObject();
                string id;
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(elements);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    id = (streamReader.ReadToEnd()).ToString();

                    return id;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception EX)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

### Code End

Answer (score 0):

The only change I needed to do is changing "var" to "dynamic" in :

```html
dynamic response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(client.GetAsync(urlParams).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```